# Can’t get Full screen from YouTube

Tags: external-display, youtube

I've got a new monitor Acer 29.5” 21:9

Everything is working fine except video streaming from YouTube.
Any video clip I try to play from YouTube has cut of picture from both sides.

[image: demo screenshot]

In other words I can’t get full screen from YouTube. When I try to play any other Video sources I do have Full screen. I have checked all settings on YouTube and on monitor but can’t find anything relevant to it.

I am using MacBook Air 2020.

I also noticed that YouTube does not have Mac version, hence the only option is browser. I tried Chrome and Safari browsers... same issue

Comment: Disable all your browser addons and try again. I had this once too, and a browser EQ extension somehow caused it. If you find out this is indeed the problem, enable them one by one to find out which one causes this.

Comment: I removed all Extensions in Chrome ... but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6375112?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming)#Pillar-boxing_and_window-boxing

Comment: Note: I don't have an issue with YouTube Full screen on MacBook itself. The problem is only when it displays on external monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video (or rather, ad) you are viewing has an aspect ratio of 16:9. Your screen has an aspect ratio of 21:9. Note how they are not the same. The only way to view this video (without hiding parts of the image) is with unused screen space to the left and right. There is *no way whatsoever* this could be worked around.

If other video players show a 16:9 video without unused space on the left and right, they are hiding substantial parts of the image.

Cinematic movies usually have an aspect ratio much closer to 21:9, so you could view these with minimal black bars or hidden parts.

Comment: Some video players might be able to stretch the video to the full screen, but with distortion.

Comment: @Daniel B - thanks for clear explanation. Does it mean that all YouTube videos are 16:9? I think that nowadays most monitors are 21:9 and all users of it experience similar issues like me?

Comment: 21:9 is not in any way common, and is used more like "two" screens than a single super wide one by most.

Answer (score -1):

Folks,
Never mind.
I found the solution by installing extension and now I'll all set

The answer was provided by @Daniel B. The issue is caused by the fact that YouTube and many other video streaming hosts provide video in 16:9 ratio. I Googled it and found a few extensions that cover 16:9 to 21:9. One that I installed was called Ultrrawide extensions for Chrome

Comment: Maybe explain what you actually did in case someone else has the same problem? Which extension do you mean?

Comment: Actually the answer was provided by Daniel B. The issue is caused by the fact that YouTube and many other video streaming hosts provide video in 16:9 ratio. I Googled it and found a few extensions that cover 16:9 to 21:9. One that I installed was called Ultrrawide extensions for Chrome.